# Getting HTTP error 401 when trying to access webmail in cpanel

Tags: php, email, cpanel, webmail

I am trying to access one of my emails through webmail in cPanel. But when I enter my email and password i get this error `"HTTP ERROR 401 horde/index.php AppConfig for “horde,” requires that you must have one of the following features: “webmail” to access the url: “/horde/”."`

I don't understand what this means and what is the cause of it.

How can I fix this?

Here's a screenshot of the full error:

[image]

Comment: _"you must have one of the following features: “webmail”_ ...sounds like the "webmail" feature isn't installed on the cPanel instance, then. Did you install this cPanel? Or is it from a hosting provider? If so you should contact their support team if you think it's supposed to be working. Either way this isn't a programming question and has nothing to do with PHP or email so I'll be voting to close it. I'd suggest that you take the [tour] and read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting anything else.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about support/config of a cPanel instance, not about programming directly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Horde Webmail was enabled in WHM.

1. Login to WHM.
2. Go to *Home* -> *Server Configuration* -> *Tweak Settings*.
3. Locate the option Enable Horde webmail.
4. Click ON to enable.
5. Click *Save*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is already enabled. but i still dont have access to the webmail. Why is that?